# XHTML and &nbsp doesnt work?

Tags: html, xhtml

Hi been out of web dev for a long time now, before when I wanted to put a space between two images i'd use &nbsp in HTML however XHTML is different? Been looking on the net but nothing is sinking in, could someone kindly help out?

Here is my code;

```
<img id ="aft" src="images/after_clamping.jpg" width="200" height="210" alt="" /><img   id ="tic" src="images/ticket.jpg" width="200" height="210" alt="" />
```

Comment: Did you include the semi-colon? `&nbsp;`

Comment: yes mate but to no avail :(

Comment: Then it should be working no problem, maybe try some CSS, like: `img#aft { margin-right: 3px; }`

Comment: <img id ="aft" src="images/after_clamping.jpg" width="200" height="210" alt="" />&nbsp;<img id ="tic" src="images/ticket.jpg" width="200" height="210" alt="" />

Comment: Don't use spaces for something like this.  Do what @faino suggests and use CSS!  Spaces are for separating words in text.

Comment: @faino cheers that works but &nbsp doesnt....wonder why! thats bugging me now!

Comment: @Brad I have used that this time thank you, works great don't know why I didnt think of that before, well out of practice!!

Comment: XHTML processes whitespace like HTML. A space between two images will render in the page. No need to use code. I do agree that CSS is a better approach, though.

Comment: Better use margin/padding for creating spaces.

Answer (score 24):

Some XHTML configurations don't seem to have the full list of entity names. Use the numerical character reference, `&#160;`

Edit:
"Some XHTML configurations" means XHTML documents without a full XHML DOCTYPE declaration. If you omit the DOCTYPE altogether, or use a shorthand one, like `<!DOCTYPE html>`, the browser will only recognise the five XML entity names. So either provide a full DOCTYPE, like `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">` or use numerical character references as above.

Comment: I had this issue, once I defined the doctype as above it solved it.  Thanks.!